# PHP function inside another function [ class ]

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code, perform a global function within a class to fill the functions of wordpress, the problem is that the only way that I could get a variable public class is as follows

```
class Core {
 public $notice;
 function __construct(){
  $this->core_function();

 }
 function core_function(){
   global $globalvar;
   $globalvar = $this;
   function notice_global(){
    global $globalvar;

    return $globalvar->notice;

   } 
 }
 function set_notice(){
  $this->notice = array('Warning');
 }

}

$GP = new Core();
$GP->set_notice();
var_dump(notice_global());
```

Any other ideas or suggestions, this code is correct or not?

Comment: Have you tried it before asking? `var_dupm()` doesn't exists.

Comment: @fusion3k that's just a typo. @OP why not `$GP->notice`? It's a public variable.

Comment: As @Flyer says, you can call directly `$GP->notice` and delete `__construnc`, `core_function` and `notice_global`. There is a particular reason to call `notice_global()` instead of `$GP->notice`

Comment: @fusion3k was my mistake is var_dump , Yes, I moved notice_global out class because I need to fill this function with WordPress own functions and do not want to create a new call to the class whenever you need to occupy

Comment: You cannot restrict the scope of methods by declaring them inside each other. So, It is confusing you and others by writing `notice_global()` inside function `core_function()`. PHP should raise a strict error. PHP will treat it as a normal method!  So what you have coded is wrong in PHP. However, because you have used the `global $globalvar;`, which is such a wrong thing to be doing, the code will work correctly! ;-/

Comment: _tldr:_ - _Never write nested methods in PHP_. _Never write nested named functions_ in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said in the comments, you need global function due to wordpress hook method (for a plugin, I suppose).

This is not necessary: there is a way to pass an object method (not a whole object) to wordpress.

You can try in this way:

```
class Core {
    public $notice;

    function get_notice()
    { return $this->notice; }

    function set_notice()
    { $this->notice = array('Warning'); }
}

$GP = new Core();
$GP->set_notice();

add_action( 'save_post', array( $GP, 'get_notice' ) );
```

Or - for a better flexibility - in this way:

```
class Core {
    public $notice;

    function get_notice()
    { return $this->notice; }

    function set_notice()
    { $this->notice = array('Warning'); }

    function add_wp_action( $hook, $method )
    { add_action( $hook, array( $this, $method ) ); }
}

$GP = new Core();
$GP->set_notice();

$GP->add_wp_action( 'save_post', 'get_notice' );
```

By this way, you can directly set all your wp hooks in the class and call they directly with an object method, without using globals variables or function tricks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding you right, but notice_global can be moved out of that class.

Globals have scope outside of classes

Comment: clear the idea is to move out for global use, since I want to take with WordPress functions without creating a new instance, the main question is whether this can cause an overload or improperly'm taking this

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for these functions. You've defined `$notice` as public property. You can access it like this: `$GP->notice`;

You might also want to read [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) on visibility of methods and properties.